# AS3 removing event listener before child still causing null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I made a game of Pong with external classes, it's currently configured so that when the playerScore/cpuScore == 1, the player, CPU and ball is removed from the stage. These are removed by the main.as file calling removePlayer(), removeBall() and removeCPU() e.g.

```
        public function removePlayer(): void
        {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        parent.removeChild(this);
        }
```

The event listener gets rid of the main loop for the element before the child is removed from stage. This works fine for both the player and CPU, but for the ball I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.classes::ball/loop()
```

Commenting out parent.removeChild(this); gets rid of the error, but obviously the ball stays visible. removeEventListener seems to have worked as the ball stops moving when called, but I'm at a loss as to why I would get the null object reference if the loop has been removed. Here is the code for my ball:

```
    package com.classes 
    {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound; 
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class ball extends MovieClip 
        {
        private var theBackground:bg;
        private var bounce:Sound = new Sound();
        private var point:Sound = new Sound();
        private var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

        public var ballSpeedX:int = -3;
        public var ballSpeedY:int = -2;

        public function ball(score:bg) 
        {
            theBackground = score;
            bounce.load(new URLRequest("com/sounds/sfxBounce.mp3"));
            point.load(new URLRequest("com/sounds/sfxScore.mp3"));
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function loop(e:Event) 
        {
            x += ballSpeedX;
            y += ballSpeedY;

            if (x <= width/2)
            {
                x = width/2;                                
                ballSpeedX *= -1;                           
                theBackground.cpuScore++;
                theBackground.updateScores();
                channel = point.play();
            } 
            else if (x >= stage.stageWidth - width/2)
            {
                x = stage.stageWidth - width/2;             
                ballSpeedX *= -1;                           
                theBackground.playerScore++;
                theBackground.updateScores();
                channel = point.play();
            }

            if (y <= height/2)
            {
                y = height/2;
                ballSpeedY *= -1;
                channel = bounce.play();
            }
            else if (y >= stage.stageHeight - height/2)
            {
                y = stage.stageHeight - height/2;
                ballSpeedY *= -1;
                channel = bounce.play();
            }
        }

        public function removeBall(): void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop) in the same class as where addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop) is ?

Comment: Yes, the loop is in the constructor function of my ball class - the removeEventListener is also in the ball class, but the function it is contained inside is called from the main document class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `if (!stage) return;` statement in the beginning of the `loop` function. Apparently you are trying to call `removeBall()` while processing another `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener, maybe on the clock or the player or elsewhere, this hits an issue with event's listener sequence already cached inside Flash. That is, if you are removing an event listener for a certain event type from within another listener of the very same event (enter frame event qualifies), the listener still gets called for that event. You should either call `removeBall()` from elsewhere, not from an enterframe listener, or just have a null check in that listener to avoid weird errors popping up.

EDIT: Apparently your `removeBall()` is called while you do `theBackground.updateScores()`, and after you do this, the ball that processes the event is already removed, thus further processing of the listener is useless. Place a `return` statement after your sound is triggered to play in all clauses that call `theBackground.updateScores()` and you should be fine.

```
      if (x <= width/2)
        {
            x = width/2;                                
            ballSpeedX *= -1;                           
            theBackground.cpuScore++;
            theBackground.updateScores();
            point.play();
            return; // here
        } 
        else if (x >= stage.stageWidth - width/2)
        {
            x = stage.stageWidth - width/2;             
            ballSpeedX *= -1;                           
            theBackground.playerScore++;
            theBackground.updateScores();
            point.play();
            return; // and here
        }
```

Comment: If the score is 1, `dispatchEvent(new Event("playerWin"));` is called from the background class, which causes a function in the main document class to call `removePlayer()`, `removeCPU()` and `removeBall()` - these aren't called in an enterframe listener.

I tried the `if (!stage) return;` too but I'm still receiving the error :(

Comment: Do you receive the line number if you debug the movie? (On the side point, make `bounce` and `point` static and load them only once. This might cause the error in `bounce.play()` call.)

Comment: First time using sounds in AS3, so not really sure how to make them static... I commented out all reference to them within the ball.as though and I'm still getting the error. When debugged, I'm getting `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at com.classes::ball/loop()[C:\Users\Craig\Desktop\GAMES\2014\PongV3\com\classes\ball.as:56]` - which is the `else if (y >= stage.stageHeight - height/2)` line, very strange!

Comment: Declare them `public static var bounce:Sound; public static var point:Sound;` then in the constructor do `if (!bounce) { bounce=new Sound(); bounce.load(...);}` and the same for `point`. This will make them static and will make them load the sounds only once per game.

Comment: Apparently `stage` is null at that point. Okay, I've got the reason. Updating post.